# Placement of buttons in nested grid in Material UI is not working properly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have created 2×2 square matrix in which last row should have nested grid and in nested I have few buttons which are not getting placed in center of the grid and even image is not displaying.

I have used [material-ui](/questions/tagged/material-ui) and React js.

```js
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import CallIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Call";
import VolumeOffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VolumeOff";
import VideocamOffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VideocamOff";
import StopScreenShareIcon from "@mui/icons-material/StopScreenShare";

const Host = () => {
  const buttons = [
    <IconButton
      key="1"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
    >
      <VideocamOffIcon />
    </IconButton>,
    <IconButton
      key="2"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
    >
      <VolumeOffIcon />
    </IconButton>,
    <IconButton
      key="3"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
    >
      <StopScreenShareIcon />
    </IconButton>,
    <IconButton
      key="4"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
    >
      <CallIcon />
    </IconButton>,

    <IconButton
      key="7"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
      onClick={() => connectWebSocket()}
    >
      conn
    </IconButton>,
    <IconButton
      key="6"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
      onClick={() => handleTimerClick(30)}
    >
      30s
    </IconButton>,
    <IconButton
      key="6"
      aria-label="call"
      color="primary"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#c4c4c4",
        borderRadius: "50%",
        margin: "10px",
      }}
      onClick={() => handleTimerClick(15)}
    >
      45s
    </IconButton>,
  ];

  return (
    <Grid container style={{ height: "100vh", position: "fixed" }}>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={12}
        style={{ height: "50%", background: "red", border: "1px solid white" }}
      >
        <Grid container style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <Grid item xs={6} className="grid1">
            <div className="part1">Participant1</div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} className="grid1">
            <div className="part1">Participant2</div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid
        item
        xs={12}
        style={{
          height: "50%",
          position: "relative",
          border: "1px solid white",
        }}
      >
        <Grid container style={{ height: "100%", position: "relative" }}>
          <Grid item xs={6} className="grid1">
            <div className="part1">Participant3</div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} className="grid1">
            <div className="part1">Participant4</div>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0 }}>
            <Grid container justifyContent="center">
              <Grid>
                <center>{buttons}</center>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

My external css

```css
.grid1 {
  background-image: url("../images/person1.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.smallimg {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  bottom: 0%;
  background-image: url("../images/person1.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.part1 {
  background-color: #fde9a9;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0%;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px -5px #cc3300;
  color: #f15a24;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

My output is:

[image: my output]

Expected is:

[image: expected is]

What I just need is all the button should be at bottom and center.